# Problema Piedra,Papel,Tijera en JavaScript

Tags: javascript

estamos haciendo un proyecto de Piedra Papel y Tijera y no conseguimos que se cumplan varias condiciones.

Explicacion del juego:

-Cuando iniciamos la pagina se inicia con onload la funcion cuentaAtras(), mientras esté activada no pueda selecionar una opcion (piedra,papel o tijera), ni darle al boton de reiniciar("Pincha Aqui").

-Tampoco conseguimos que una vez que se ha finalizado la cuenta atrás no deje al jugador reiniciar hasta que elija una opcion.
Paso el código Javascript

```js
var userCount = 0;
var iaCount = 0;
var alerta = "Espera";
var x = 5;
var activo = true;
//Array con las opciones
var imagenes=new Array(
  ['img/PPT_Roca.png'],
  ['img/PPT_Papel.png'],
  ['img/PPT_Tijera.png'],
  ['img/PPT_Lagarto.png'],
  ['img/PPT_Spock.png']
  );


  //Funcion para comparar lo que ha elegido el jugador y la maquina-->

function opcion(humano){
 var cpu = getRandomInt();
 var resultado_texto = ["empate","ganas","pierdes"];
 var nombre = ["Piedra","Papel","Tijera"];
 var eleccion = true;
 var jugada = [
        [0,1,2,],
        [2,0,1,],
        [1,2,0,]
  ];

  respuestaIA.src=imagenes[cpu];

  var resultado = jugada[cpu][humano];


  if (resultado_texto[resultado] == "pierdes"){
      eleccion = false;
      iaCount++;
      console.log("Has perdido, parguela");
      document.getElementById('contador_ia').innerHTML = iaCount;
      document.getElementsByClassName('respuesta').innerHTML = "has perdido";
    }
  else if (resultado_texto[resultado] == "ganas"){
      eleccion = false;
      userCount++;
      console.log("Has ganado,Puto");
      document.getElementById('contador_usuario').innerHTML = userCount;
      document.getElementsByClassName('respuesta').innerHTML = "has ganado";
  }
  else{
    eleccion = false;
    console.log("no hace nada");
  }


  console.log(resultado);
  console.log("HUMANO: " + nombre[humano]);
  console.log("CPU: " + nombre[cpu]);
  console.log(resultado_texto[resultado]);

}


  //funcion para optener un numero random-->
function getRandomInt() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (4 - 0 + 1)) + 0;
}


  //Variables del DOM-->

  DOM_contador=document.getElementById("cAtras");
  DOM_piedra=document.getElementById("piedra_btn");            
  DOM_papel=document.getElementById("papel_btn");
  DOM_tijeras=document.getElementById("tijeras_btn");
  DOM_reiniciar=document.getElementById("btn_reiniciar");




  //Listener de los botones-->

  DOM_piedra.addEventListener("click",function() {
          unlock(0);
          //reiniciar();
          });
  DOM_papel.addEventListener("click",function() {
          unlock(1);
          //reiniciar();
          });
  DOM_tijeras.addEventListener("click",function() {
          unlock(2);
          //reiniciar();
          });
  DOM_reiniciar.addEventListener("click",function() {
          reiniciar();
  });

  //Funcion para evitar que el jugador pueda elgir antes de que termine la cuenta atras


function unlock(humano){
  if(activo == false)
  {
    alert(alerta);
  }
  else
  {
    opcion(humano);
  }
}


   //Funcion para evitar que pulse el boton de reiniciar la funcion 
   //cuentaAtras() sin elegir una opcion


function reiniciar(tiempo,eleccion){
  if(eleccion == false && tiempo == false ){
    cuentaAtras()
  }
  else {
    alert("Elige una opcion");
  }
}

  //Funcion de la cuenta atras-->


function cuentaAtras() {
  var x = 5;
  console.log('se ejecuta la cuenta atras');
  var tiempo  = true;
  activo = false;
  DOM_contador.innerHTML = x;
  var intervalo = setInterval(function() {
        if(x > 1){
          x--;
          console.log("estoy en el if");
          DOM_contador.innerHTML = x;
        }
        else {
          activo = true;
          tiempo = false;
          console.log("estoy en el else");
          DOM_contador.innerHTML = "Ya";
          clearInterval(intervalo);
        }
  },600);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<title>index</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="css/CssGeneral.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="css/CssPartida2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

</head>

<body onload="cuentaAtras()">

<div class="container-fluid">

  <!--Barrita de navegacion-->
  <div class="col-12 row navbar">
    <div class="col-lg-8 row">
    <img src="img/Icono_volver.png" class="img_nav " id="pgmenu">
    <img src="img/Icono_registro.png" class="img_nav " id="pgregistro">
    <img src="img/Icono_modo.png" class="img_nav " id="pgjuego">
  </div>
  <!--Log in-->
    <div class="col-lg-4 pad_nav alinear_der" style="text-align:center">
        <input type="text" id="loginuser" placeholder="Usuario" class="form-control navbarlogin">
        <input type="text" id="loginpass" placeholder="Contraseña" class="form-control navbarlogin">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-light navbarlogin">Iniciar Sesion</button>
    </div>
  </div>
                            <!--Titulo Partida-->

    <div class="col-12 row">
        <h1>PARTIDA</h1>

    </div>

    <div class="row">                  <!--Contenedor del juego-->
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 row">        <!--Primera Columna-->

                <div class="col-12">
                <h3>Elige:</h3>
                </div>


        <div class="col-12 row">

                            <div class="col-6">
                            <img src="img/PPT_Roca.png" alt="Piedra" class="img_PPT" id="piedra_btn">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-6">
                            <img src="img/PPT_Papel.png" alt="Papel" class="img_PPT" id="papel_btn">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-6">
                            <img src="img/PPT_Tijera.png" alt="Tijeras" class="img_PPT" id="tijeras_btn">
                            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="row">
               <div class="col-12">
                    <img src="img/Partida_0010_Confirm.png" alt="confirmar" class="img_boton">
               </div>
          </div>


     </div>







        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">    <!--Segunda Columna-->
            <div class="row">

                  <h3>Cuenta atrás:</h3>             <!--Cuenta atras/Titulo-->

            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <p id="cAtras">5</p>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <button id="btn_reiniciar">Pincha aqui</button>
            </div>

                <h3>Contador: </h3>

                <h3>usuario: <p id="contador_usuario"></p></h3>

                <h3>ia: <p id="contador_ia"></p></h3>

                <h3 id="respuesta"></h3>

        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">     <!-- Tercera Columna-->
          <h3>IA</h3>

              <!---Boton contrincante--->
              <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-12">
                  <img src="img/Signo_de_Interrogacion.png" id="respuestaIA" alt="interrogación" class="img_boton">
                  </div>
              </div>


        </div>



    </div>   <!--Fin del Contenedor del juego-->

</div>






<!--Juego-->

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

La Variable x Ya Existe en Global y además no la reinicias cuando reinicias.
Yo creo que así ira.

```js
var userCount = 0;
var iaCount = 0;
var alerta = "Espera";
var x = 5;
var activo = true;
//Array con las opciones
var imagenes = ["img/PPT_Roca.png","img/PPT_Papel.png","img/PPT_Tijera.png","img/PPT_Lagarto.png","img/PPT_Spock.png"];


  //Funcion para comparar lo que ha elegido el jugador y la maquina-->

function opcion(humano){
 var cpu = getRandomInt();
 var resultado_texto = ["empate","ganas","pierdes"];
 var nombre = ["Piedra","Papel","Tijera"];
 var eleccion = true;
 var jugada = [];
 jugada[0] = [0,1,2];
 jugada[1] = [2,0,1];
 jugada[2] = [1,2,0];

  respuestaIA.src=imagenes[cpu];

  var resultado = jugada[cpu][humano];


  if (resultado == "pierdes"){
      eleccion = false;
      iaCount++;
      console.log("Has perdido, parguela");
      document.getElementById('contador_ia').innerHTML = iaCount - 1;
      document.getElementsByClassName('respuesta').innerHTML = "has perdido";
    }
  elseif (resultado == "ganas"){
      eleccion = false;
      userCount++;
      console.log("Has ganado,Puto");
      document.getElementById('contador_usuario').innerHTML = userCount - 1;
      document.getElementsByClassName('respuesta').innerHTML = "has ganado";
  }
  else{
    eleccion = false;
    console.log("no hace nada");
  }


  console.log(resultado);
  console.log("HUMANO: " + nombre[humano]);
  console.log("CPU: " + nombre[cpu]);
  console.log(resultado_texto[resultado]);

}


  //funcion para optener un numero random-->
function getRandomInt() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (4 - 1));
}


  //Variables del DOM-->

  DOM_contador=document.getElementById("cAtras");
  DOM_piedra=document.getElementById("piedra_btn");                                             
  DOM_papel=document.getElementById("papel_btn");
  DOM_tijeras=document.getElementById("tijeras_btn");
  DOM_reiniciar=document.getElementById("btn_reiniciar");




  //Listener de los botones-->

  DOM_piedra.addEventListener("click",function() {
          unlock(0);
          //reiniciar();
          });
  DOM_papel.addEventListener("click",function() {
          unlock(1);
          //reiniciar();
          });
  DOM_tijeras.addEventListener("click",function() {
          unlock(2);
          //reiniciar();
          });
  DOM_reiniciar.addEventListener("click",function() {
          reiniciar();
  });

  //Funcion para evitar que el jugador pueda elgir antes de que termine la cuenta atras


function unlock(humano){
  if(activo == false)
  {
    alert(alerta);
  }
  else
  {
    opcion(humano);
  }
}


   //Funcion para evitar que pulse el boton de reiniciar la funcion 
   //cuentaAtras() sin elegir una opcion


function reiniciar(tiempo,eleccion){
  if(eleccion == false && tiempo == false ){
    cuentaAtras();
  }
  else {
    x = 5;
   alert("Elige una opcion");
  }
}

  //Funcion de la cuenta atras-->


function cuentaAtras() {
  //var x = 5; Esta Variable Ya Existe en Global
  console.log('se ejecuta la cuenta atras');
  var tiempo  = true;
  activo = false;
  DOM_contador.innerHTML = x;
  var intervalo = setInterval(function() {
        if(x > 1){
          x--;
          console.log("estoy en el if");
          DOM_contador.innerHTML = x;
        }
        else {
          activo = true;
          tiempo = false;
          console.log("estoy en el else");
          DOM_contador.innerHTML = "Ya";
          clearInterval(intervalo);
        }
  },600);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body onload="cuentaAtras()">

<div class="container-fluid">

  <!--Barrita de navegacion-->
  <div class="col-12 row navbar">
    <div class="col-lg-8 row">
    <img src="img/Icono_volver.png" class="img_nav " id="pgmenu">
    <img src="img/Icono_registro.png" class="img_nav " id="pgregistro">
    <img src="img/Icono_modo.png" class="img_nav " id="pgjuego">
  </div>
  <!--Log in-->
    <div class="col-lg-4 pad_nav alinear_der" style="text-align:center">
        <input type="text" id="loginuser" placeholder="Usuario" class="form-control navbarlogin">
        <input type="text" id="loginpass" placeholder="Contraseña" class="form-control navbarlogin">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-light navbarlogin">Iniciar Sesion</button>
    </div>
  </div>
                            <!--Titulo Partida-->

    <div class="col-12 row">
        <h1>PARTIDA</h1>

    </div>

    <div class="row">                                           <!--Contenedor del juego-->
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 row">                   <!--Primera Columna-->

                <div class="col-12">
                <h3>Elige:</h3>
                </div>


        <div class="col-12 row">

                            <div class="col-6">
                            <img src="img/PPT_Roca.png" alt="Piedra" class="img_PPT" id="piedra_btn">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-6">
                            <img src="img/PPT_Papel.png" alt="Papel" class="img_PPT" id="papel_btn">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-6">
                            <img src="img/PPT_Tijera.png" alt="Tijeras" class="img_PPT" id="tijeras_btn">
                            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="row">
               <div class="col-12">
                    <img src="img/Partida_0010_Confirm.png" alt="confirmar" class="img_boton">
               </div>
          </div>


     </div>







        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">    <!--Segunda Columna-->
            <div class="row">

                  <h3>Cuenta atrás:</h3>             <!--Cuenta atras/Titulo-->

            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <p id="cAtras">5</p>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <button id="btn_reiniciar">Pincha aqui</button>
            </div>

                <h3>Contador: </h3>

                <h3>usuario: <p id="contador_usuario"></p></h3>

                <h3>ia: <p id="contador_ia"></p></h3>

                <h3 id="respuesta"></h3>

        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">     <!-- Tercera Columna-->
          <h3>IA</h3>

              <!---Boton contrincante--->
              <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-12">
                  <img src="img/Signo_de_Interrogacion.png" id="respuestaIA" alt="interrogación" class="img_boton">
                  </div>
              </div>


        </div>



    </div>   <!--Fin del Contenedor del juego-->

</div>






<!--Juego-->

</body>
</html>
```

---

Acabo de Hacer la App de Cero, a ver si te sirve así:

```js
function Aleatorio(Minimo,Maximo){
    var posibilidades = Maximo - Minimo;
    var a = Math.random() * posibilidades;
    a = Math.floor(a);
    return parseInt(Minimo) + a;
}
function Juguemos(){
    var NumeroTemp = Aleatorio(1,3);
    var BoxOpcion1 = document.getElementById("Opcion1").checked;
    var BoxOpcion2 = document.getElementById("Opcion2").checked;
    var BoxOpcion3 = document.getElementById("Opcion3").checked;
    var NumeroUser = 0;
    var Numero = parseInt(NumeroTemp);
    if ( BoxOpcion1 ) { NumeroUser = 1 }
    if ( BoxOpcion2 ) { NumeroUser = 2 }
    if ( BoxOpcion3 ) { NumeroUser = 3 }
    if ( Numero == 1 && NumeroUser == 1 ) { alert("Empate"); }
    if ( Numero == 1 && NumeroUser == 2 ) { alert("Ganaste"); }
    if ( Numero == 1 && NumeroUser == 3 ) { alert("Perdiste"); }
    if ( Numero == 2 && NumeroUser == 2 ) { alert("Empate"); }
    if ( Numero == 2 && NumeroUser == 3 ) { alert("Ganaste"); }
    if ( Numero == 2 && NumeroUser == 1 ) { alert("Perdiste"); }
    if ( Numero == 3 && NumeroUser == 3 ) { alert("Empate"); }
    if ( Numero == 3 && NumeroUser == 1 ) { alert("Ganaste"); }
    if ( Numero == 3 && NumeroUser == 2 ) { alert("Perdiste"); }
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<html lang="es_ES" >
<meta charset="UTF-8" >
<meta name="author" content="Pol Flórez Viciana" >
<meta name="owner" content="Pol Flórez Viciana" >
<meta name="keywords" content="Pol, Software, Piedra,Papel,y,Tijera" >
<title>Juego Piedra Papel y Tijeras ON-LINE de Pol Software</title>
<meta name="description" content="Este es el Juego de Piedra Papel y Tijeras ON-LINE de Pol Software" >
<meta name="robots" content="index, dofollow" >
</head>
<body >
<!-- Este es el Juego de Piedra Papel y Tijera de Pol Software ON-LINE Para la Web -->

<!-- Centramos Todo el Contenido -->    
<center>
    <!-- Creamos Todo el Contenido de una Seccion -->
    <section>
        <!-- Creamos Todo el Contenido del Usuario Para el Juego -->
        <h1 style="text-align: center;" >Juego Piedra Papel y Tijera ON-LINE de Pol Software</h1>
        <p>Elije la Opción con la Que Juegas Contra la CPU y Pulsa Ok Cuando Estes Listo.</p>
        <p>Pulsa CTRL+F5 Para Volver Al Inicio.</p>
        <form id="Formulario" name="Formulario" >
            
            <input type="radio" name="Opcion" id="Opcion1" checked />Piedra<br><br>
            <input type="radio" name="Opcion" id="Opcion2"  />Papel<br><br>
            <input type="radio" name="Opcion" id="Opcion3" />Tijera<br><br>
            <input type="button" id="Ok" value="Ok" onclick="Juguemos()" /><br><br>
        </form>
    </section>
</center>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
window.onload = function () {
                var userCount = 0;
                var iaCount = 0;
                var alerta = "Espera";
                var x = 5;
                var activo = false;
                //Array con las opciones
                var imagenes = new Array(
                        ['img/PPT_Roca.png'],
                        ['img/PPT_Papel.png'],
                        ['img/PPT_Tijera.png'],
                        ['img/PPT_Lagarto.png'],
                        ['img/PPT_Spock.png']
                        );
                //Funcion para comparar lo que ha elegido el jugador y la maquina-->

                function opcion(humano) {
                    var cpu = getRandomInt();
                    var resultado_texto = ["empate", "ganas", "pierdes"];
                    var nombre = ["Piedra", "Papel", "Tijera"];
                    var eleccion = true;
                    var jugada = [
                        [0, 1, 2, ],
                        [2, 0, 1, ],
                        [1, 2, 0, ]
                    ];
                    respuestaIA.src = imagenes[cpu];
                    var resultado = jugada[cpu][humano];
                    if (resultado_texto[resultado] == "pierdes") {
                        eleccion = false;
                        iaCount++;
                        console.log("Has perdido, parguela");
                        document.getElementById('contador_ia').innerHTML = iaCount;
                        document.getElementsByClassName('respuesta').innerHTML = "has perdido";
                    } else if (resultado_texto[resultado] == "ganas") {
                        eleccion = false;
                        userCount++;
                        console.log("Has ganado,Puto");
                        document.getElementById('contador_usuario').innerHTML = userCount;
                        document.getElementsByClassName('respuesta').innerHTML = "has ganado";
                    } else {
                        eleccion = false;
                        console.log("no hace nada");
                    }


                    console.log(resultado);
                    console.log("HUMANO: " + nombre[humano]);
                    console.log("CPU: " + nombre[cpu]);
                    console.log(resultado_texto[resultado]);
                }


                //funcion para optener un numero random-->
                function getRandomInt() {
                    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (4 - 0 + 1)) + 0;
                }


                //Variables del DOM-->

                DOM_contador = document.getElementById("cAtras");
                DOM_piedra = document.getElementById("piedra_btn");
                DOM_papel = document.getElementById("papel_btn");
                DOM_tijeras = document.getElementById("tijeras_btn");
                DOM_reiniciar = document.getElementById("btn_reiniciar");
                //Listener de los botones-->

                DOM_piedra.addEventListener("click", function () {
                    if (activo == true) {
                        unlock(0);
                        //reiniciar();
                    }
                });
                DOM_papel.addEventListener("click", function () {
                    if (activo == true) {
                        unlock(1);
                        //reiniciar()            ;
                    }
                });
                DOM_tijeras.addEventListener("click", function () {
                    if (activo == true) {
                        unlock(2);
                        //rei            niciar();
                    }
                });
                DOM_reiniciar.addEventListener("click", function () {
                    if (activo == true) {
                        reiniciar();
                    }
                });
                //Funcion para evitar que el jugador pue            da elgir antes de que termine la cuenta atras


                function unlock(humano) {
                    if (activo == false)
                    {
                        alert(alerta);
                    } else
                    {
                        opcion(humano);
                    }
                }


                //Funcion para evitar que pulse el bot            on de reiniciar la funcion 
                //cuentaAtras() sin elegir una opcion


                function reiniciar(tiempo, eleccion) {
                    cuentaAtras();
                }

                //Funcion de la cuenta atras-->


                function cuentaAtras() {
                    var x = 5;
                    console.log('se ejecuta la cuenta atras');
                    var tiempo = true;
                    activo = false;
                    DOM_contador.innerHTML = x;
                    var intervalo = setInterval(function () {
                        if (x > 1) {
                            x--;
                            console.log("estoy en el if");
                            DOM_contador.innerHTML = x;
                        } else {
                            activo = true;
                            tiempo = false;
                            console.log("estoy en el else");
                            DOM_contador.innerHTML = "Ya";
                            clearInterval(intervalo);
                        }
                    }, 600);
                }
                cuentaAtras();
            }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">

        <title>index</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link href="css/CssGeneral.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="css/CssPartida2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <script>
            
        </script>
```